# MFC Menu Drop Down (Screenshot included)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, drop-down-menu

I'm having difficulties with an MFC application menu drop down. I want the drop down to display all items when it is clicked. Instead it displays arrows which the user must click in order to show the drop down items.

See the pic below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a feature of the MFC feature pack where the menu will hide rarely used items. You should be able to disable this feature using the [CMFCMenuBar::SetShowAllCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983708.aspx) method.

Comment: Even after calling SetShowAllCommands() the menu items are not show. I came across this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/6aadc417-b2ce-48dc-a96d-1b023797db59 which specifies a user can change the behavior during toolbar customization by using the Customize dialog box. This dialog box is available in your app under View->Toolbars and Docking Windows->Customize under the Options tab. I unchecked "Menus show recently used commands first" as well as "Show full menus after a short delay". Now it works as I wanted it to. Your answer led me to the correct answer.